# There is a remote git branch but no match local branch, how to delete the remote one

Tags: git

The following command:

`$ git branch -a`

yields

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/foo
  remotes/origin/master
```

but I don't want `remotes/origin/feature/foo` branch.  What could I have done to have this?  How do I delete it?

I've tried this:

`git push origin --delete origin/feature/foo`

but I get this:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/feature/foo
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to '...my remote repo...'
```

Any ideas?  Many thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
git push origin feature/foo
```

`git` really sees

```
git push origin feature/foo:feature/foo
```

what means "push `feature/foo` (left side) to remotes `feature/foo` (right side).

With

```
git push origin :feature/foo
```

you push "nothing" to `feature/foo`